# How do I tell how much disk is being used from BitLocker?

Tags: windows-10, disk-space, bitlocker

How do I tell how much data on the disk is being used for BitLocker encryption?

I am trying to see how much disk space I could save if I did not have BitLocker on the drive.

The drive this is on is not the primary drive.

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes any sense.  As I understand it, bitlocker encrypts the entire partition.

Comment: @davidgo I'm talking about the storage used by the encryption table, as BitLocker encrypted files might take up more storage than non-encrypted files.

Comment: It appears you have some misconceptions about how BitLocker works. There is no encryption table. Wikipedia has many articles on full disk encryption (they also apply to only encrypting partitions), I suggest you read into the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive not been able to find supporting evidence for this online,  but my understanding (which comes from LUKS - the equivalent tool for Linux) is that Bitlocker disk overhead is negligible - I would be surprised if it is as much as 1 Megabyte.

Bitlocker would have a header which marks the volume as a Bitlocker encrypted one, and will contain (multiple) encrypted copies of the key (for different means of unlocking the device).  The remaining data is an encrypted version of the filesystem/files on the drive, taking up the same number of bytes as the original.